# Template for a datagrid

Tags: wpf

```
<DataGrid AutoGenerateColumns="False" Height="200" Margin="0,63,0,0" Name="dataGrid1" MouseDoubleClick="dataGrid1_MouseDoubleClick">
    <DataGrid.Columns>
        <DataGridTextColumn Header="Hospital Name" Width="100" Binding="{Binding hosp_name}"/>
         <DataGridTextColumn Header="Order Number" Width="100" Binding="{Binding ordID}"/>
         <DataGridTextColumn Header="Order Date" Width="*" Binding="{Binding placedDate}"  />
    </DataGrid.Columns>    
</DataGrid>
```

Hey guys, I'm new with wpf, how can I make this into a template so I can render it each time I create a new tab programatically?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Wrap it in a [`DataTemplate`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.datatemplate.aspx) and assign it as `ContentTemplate` of the `TabControl`.

Comment: I got it to show up but now i'm trying to fill it with data after it loads by using ItemsSource="{Binding Path=getOrders}" where getOrders is in another class called dataHelper. I just get an empty datagrid... any tips?